# dbext freeze when running SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, neovim, dbext

I am using neovim with dbext;

In my init.vim i have this line

```
let g:dbext_default_profile_local_PSQL = 'type=PGSQL'
```

I have test file: test.sql.

In file is:

```
select * from products;
```

when i run \sel

nvim shows: 
    dbext: Executing SQL at 22:56Password:

and it freeze and i can only kill it.
What can i do about it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `psql` is prompting for a password.

Try adding `let dbext_default_PGSQL_cmd_options = '-w'` in `.vimrc`.